# Unable to set the value for the second series in a chart

Tags: vba, excel

i am creating some vba to update the series ranges for a chart I have in my workbook.  I am able to update series 1 however series 2 returns a 1004 error when i try and run the code.

Here is what I am working with

```
graphRange = startColumn(1) & "573:" & endColumn(1) & "573"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Input Table'!" & graphRange

graphRange = startColumn(1) & "601:" & endColumn(1) & "606"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='Input Table'!" & graphRange
```

Comment: Obvious Qn: Does the Chart have two series?

Comment: Yes it does I found the issue series two should be 601 in both instances and not 601 and 606.  Its been a long day it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  I had incorrect values for the second series the range should be 601 in both locations not 601 and 606.